# soft stoppped working

Tags: c#

this is might be really weird, but I have no idea what kinda wizardry of this. Basically, my Visual Studio stopped responding to my changes, it stopped building solution. I can comment code, which would completely ruin the logic of program, and Visual Studio will still run program that I guess it has in memory. It's really annoying, and I have no idea what it is. I keep restarting software, but it's still does the same. It's a licensed software. I was wondering If someone knew what was going on. Thanks!

Comment: tried,didnt help. it would help for couple of minutes, but then problem comes again randomly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen this a few times, and usually one of or a combination of the following will work:

- Clean the solution, then build it.
- Change the from "Release" to Debug (or vice-cversa) then clean and build, then revert back.
- Close visual studio and manually delete everything in the \bin directory
- For an asp.net website, close visual studio and delete the files in C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files (Path will vary depending on your machine setup  This is where my ASP.NET versino 4 files are compiled to.)

Comment: Well, that clears up things for me. Appreciate it!